# PyTorch not downloading

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I go to the PyTorch website and select the following options

PyTorch Build: Stable (1.2)

Your OS: Windows

Package: pip

Language: Python 3.7

CUDA: None

(All of these are correct)

Than it displays a command to run

`pip3 install torch==1.2.0+cpu torchvision==0.4.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

I have already tried to mix around the the different options but none of them has worked.

---

ERROR: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.2.0+cpu (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.2.0+cpu`

I tried to do pip install pytorch but pytorch doesn't support pypi

Answer (score 1):

I've been in same situation. 
My prob was,  the python version... I mean, in the 'bit' way.

It was 32 bit that the python I'd installed.
You should check which bit of python you installed. 
you can check in the app in setting, search python, then you will see the which bit you've installed.

After I installed the 64 bit of Python, it solved.

I hope you figure it out!

environment : win 10

Comment: This worked for me but it broke pip3 when I uninstalled the 32-bit version of python. So I had to install with py -m pip install. Windows system

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can't find a version called "1.2.0+cpu" from it's list of versions that it can find (0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2). Try looking for one of those versions on the PyTorch website.

Comment: I cant seem to find one that says 0.1.2 I am going to their  website and selecting all of the options that was listed in the question and that is the one it has generated for me. I'm trying to install it with pip and without CUDA. Is that the problem

Comment: There does not seem to be an issue with trying to install it without CUDA, but given the option exists on their website to install it with CUDA, I would try it to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I cant install PyTorch because I am running python 32-bit. This may or may not be the problem but this is the only possible error that I could see this being the cause.